# Cannot open my development server (localhost:3000)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack-dev-server

I just did my first react app in desktop and i cleanup my pc for slowness.after when i open my react app and hit

npm start -> this error popped-up

```
module.js:549
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/compat'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Azran\Desktop\try\node_modules\raw-body\node_modules\depd\index.js:11:24)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! try@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the try@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional                             logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be`enter code here` found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Azran\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-13T18_11_38_805Z-debug.log
```

Comment: As your error message says, it looks like "./lib/compat" is missing or removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, install npm modules again

```
npm install
```

Or, if you use yarn:

```
yarn install
//or, just
yarn
```

Then, you should be able to start the project normally:

```
npm start

// or,
yarn start
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node-modules folder and then run

```
npm install
```

Comment: Thank you for rplying me... and still same error popping up

Comment: run `npm list -g --depth 0` and share the result here. Maybe there is an issue with your global packages